# Retrieve Person Account Details through Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I would like to fetch the field data in my email template from Service cloud person account. There is no syntax error, however it's not returning any values.

I also tried with Contact object in 'RetrieveSalesforceObjects' function, however it shows invalid field name error.

Can anyone help with this?

```
%%[

SET @Id = AttributeValue("Id") /*ContactID from DE*/

set @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
   "Account",
   "Store__pc",
   "Id", "=", @Id )

if RowCount(@subscriberRows) == 1 then /* there should only be one row */
  set @subscriberRow = Row(@subscriberRows, 1)
  set @Store = Field(@subscriberRows,"Store__pc")
  
endif

]%%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be mixing two different IDs here:

- `ContactID` in the context of Marketing Cloud is an integer
- `Id` of an *Account* object which is a string in the format of `001+15characters`

If the `ContactID` you have stored in your DE is a number, it's the MC Contact ID and it's natural you will not find any matching records of the Account object with the same value in the `Id` field.

In out of the box integration the MC-type ContactID is not stored in Sales / Service Cloud, so this might be kind of a dead end if you can only rely on an integer `Contact ID`

---

You would be much better off using a Marketing Cloud `Subscriber Key` or `Contact Key` which in standard integrations using MC Connect represents the ID of the Contact object in a Salesforce org. This type of ID uses the `003+15characters` format.

In a person account setup, this value is stored on the `PersonContactID` field in Sales Cloud.

---

**Updated based on OP's comment**:

In your original code we see you retrieving the store information from the Account object where it's named `Store__pc`. The `__pc` suffix means that for this PersonAccount this particular field was created on the level of the PersonContact (pc), so you actually have two ways of retrieving this information through ampscript:

*From the Account object:*

```
RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
    "Account", 
    "Store__pc", 
    "PersonContactID", "=", @Id)
```

The `003...` ID is stored in the PersonContactID field

---

*From the Contact object:*

```
RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
    "Contact", 
    "Store__c", 
    "Id", "=", @Id)
```

The `003...` ID is the ID of the Contact and since you are retrieving the field data from the object to which the field belongs, you need to use `Store__c` instead of `Store__pc`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I use salesforce data entry event in Journey which is created on ContactPointConsent object. This object doesn't have 'Store__pc' data. I can take contact ID from this object and get other values through Ampscript. How can I do it in Ampscript? My contact ID is the ContactID from SF which starts with 003.

Comment: @salesforce-user I updated my answer based on your comment

Comment: it worked, thanks @Rafał Wolsztyniak